# Gracefully handle duplicated actions on posts in review queues

Tags: bug, review-queues

Steps to reproduce:

1. Navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts
2. Open the post in a new tab
3. Vote to delete the post in the new tab
4. Come back to the original tab and click on the `Delete` button

Expected: possibly receive a message that I have already voted to delete the post OR a successful delete message. Then move to the next low quality post.

Actual: receive a weird-looking message that I have already voted to delete the post and disappears in less than a second. I am stuck in the current post and I am forced to refresh the browser's tab. Here is the image with the message:

[image]

Comment: ok there's a slight bug, but if you downvoted/deleted, you must know it, so why not using "skip" afterwards?

Comment: I wouldn't know exactly the effect of skipping in this case. E.G: does it count as me skipping or as me voting to delete in queue terms? Anyway, it doesn't really matter. I wasn't looking for a workaround but rather notifying the situation

Comment: link+delete + skipping "cheats" the max number of items you can process a day. If you want it recorded don't delete outside the review.